# How to put run time operations on object data while using ngFor Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, ngfor

I have code like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let oldRow of displayData">
 <span>{{ dataTime }}</span> // getting data like " Fri Aug 31 2018 15:28:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) "
  </div>
```

I want only time converted in 12 hours format like " 3:28 PM " to display, How can I get it.

Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: use [Date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, any example?

Comment: `{{ dataTime | date: 'h:mm a'}}`

Comment: Use date pipe as @AlekseySolovey suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write custom pipe for this one.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return super.transform(value, 'dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm a');
  }
}
```

After creating this pipe, you can get the value as a parameter in this pipe & transform it according to your need.
Hope this helps.